# Logic to decode in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table which has values to the power of 2 (this is basically multiple choice questions answers)

```
ID | Value | Answer   | QuestionId
1  |    1  | Answer 1 |  1
2  |    2  | Answer 2 |  1
3  |    4  | Answer 3 |  1
4  |    8  | Answer 4 |  1
```

I have another table which contains the choices user has selected. But these choices are summed up. Like if the user has selected only first choice, the result is 1 if the user has selected first and second, the result is 3. if the user has selected first and third the result is 5 and so on.

```
QuestionId | Result
1          |  3
2          |  1
```

I want to get back the choices selected from this result. How can I do it in SQL

Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: I don't think you would be able to track back to which answers the person gave. If they answered 1 and 3 then the sum would be 4. However, if they answered only 4, then the sum would also be 4. There would be no way of knowing which of the two options they chose. Edit: Sorry, didn't see powers of two!

Comment: There is absolutely no logic here I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @JCollerton If the values are powers of two, then you can decode which answers were selected.

Comment: @Jcollerton That's why they used powers of two.

Comment: @JCollerton If user answered 1&3 then output will be 5 not 4

Comment: You should consider changing the second table to add the id of the option. That will make your work a lot easier. This design, although somewhat functional is far to complex to a simple relationship problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is not indented to be a bitmask? i.e. OR to compose and AND to decompose?  That works for your examples.

Comment: @AlexK, yes, it was bitmasked to compose. That was done in C# code. Now we need to decompose in SQL. How can I do that ? Any reference?

Comment: @JorgeCampos, unfortunately I cannot do that. I need to use existing schema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> @AlexK, yes, it was bitmasked to compose. That was done in C# code. Now we need to decompose in SQL. How can I do that ?

Use `&`:

```
CREATE TABLE T(ID INT, Value INT) INSERT T VALUES 
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 4),
  (4, 8)

DECLARE @CHOICE INT = 1 | 4

SELECT * FROM T
WHERE
   @CHOICE & Value != 0
```

For

```
ID  Value
1   1
3   4
```

Comment: It was not so easy to decode the logic in existing application. However, the Bitwise AND is the one which worked for me. I took the choice sum, AND it with each choices for that question in a loop and which gave the choice was the one which user has selected

Comment: @Anuja I am not sure why you selected this post as the answer. It does not appear to be a correct answer to my eye. A correct answer would have to bitwise AND every possible answer to each of the result values in order to produce the choices that the user selected. You sound like you ended up solving the problem in a language other than SQL as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only have four possible answers, the simplest solution (and easiest to understand when you read your code later) is probably just to create a lookup table with the values 0-15 as keys and four other columns with values that show which answers were selected corresponding to each key. It's not as elegant as a bitmask, but I think your maintenance programmer will probably thank you later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like

```
select cast(Result::bit(4) & B'0001' as int)
union select cast(Result::bit(4) & B'0010' as int)
union select cast(Result::bit(4) & B'0100' as int)
union select cast(Result::bit(4) & B'1000' as int);
```

(This is for Postgres; adapt as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

## Example data set and tables

Using MySQL sytax. No attempt has been made to optimize this query

```
CREATE TABLE result_set (
    QuestionId INT auto_increment primary key,
    Result INT UNSIGNED
);

INSERT INTO result_set (QuestionId, Result) VALUES
(1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4);

CREATE TABLE answer_map (
    mask INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Answer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO answer_map(mask, Answer) VALUES
(1, 'Answer 1'),
 (2, 'Answer 2'),
(4, 'Answer 3'),
 (8, 'Answer 4');


SELECT
    r.QuestionId, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.Answer ORDER BY a.Answer) as answer_list
FROM
    result_set r
        LEFT JOIN answer_map a ON r.Result & a.mask != 0
GROUP BY r.QuestionId
    ;
```

## The result

```
QuestionId  | answer_list
-------------------------------
1           | Answer 1,Answer 2
2           | Answer 1
3           | Answer 3
```